# How can I determine if an Excel chart has any data series

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I am trying to create a chart with VBA with the following line:

```
Set StressChart = INFsheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatterLines)
```

Sometimes the chart already comes with a (nonsense) datapoint, and I have to delete it:

```
StressChart.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Delete
```

However, sometimes there is no data yet, and the FullSeriesCollection object does not exist. This causes an error.

How can I predict if there will be data, or how can I test if there is data?

My locals tree looks as follows:
[image]

The snap is taken at the following breakpoint:
[image]

The code runs fine as it is shown above, but if un-comment the second green line (marked "Disabled for debug"), I get the following error: "Parameter not valid".

Answer (score 1):

Please, try:

```
If `StressChart.Chart.FullSeriesCollection.count > 0 Then StressChart.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Delete`
```

**Edited:**
Using the above suggestion in your code as:

```
If `.Chart.FullSeriesCollection.count > 0 Then .Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Delete`
```

does it rise the same error?

Comment: I have checked the 'locals' window, and the Chart object does not seem to have FullSeriesCollection, so trying to call it would just give another error.

Comment: @Orbit I'm afraid, I cannot get you. The `Chart` should have this property. It is 0 if any series has not been added. I cannot understand your question, I am afraid. I will delete my answer. If you can share a workbook with such an example of strange pseudo chart, I will try looking at it and try finding a solution.

Comment: @FaneDuru: Don't delete it yet, maybe I'm doing something wrong. I'll try to give more information.

Comment: @Orbit Using the updated answer in that way, will also raise any error?

Comment: No, it runs without error, but for some files a 'ghost' series is created, which only shows up in the legend. I have implemented your suggestion, and then it seems to work on all types of input files, although I still cant find the 'FullSeriesCollection' in the locals tree.

Comment: @Orbit I cannot get you again... Do you mean that `.Chart.FullSeriesCollection.count` returns zero, but a series still exists in the chart? If so,  it should be created by your following code creating `NewSeries`. Please, try inserting another similar line after all added such `NewSeries`. `Debug.Print .Chart.FullSeriesCollection.count`.  Does it return what you expect it to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235451/discussion-between-orbit-and-faneduru).

Answer (score 0):

To create a diagram without unnecessary rows:

```
Dim mychart as chart
Set mychart=activesheet.chartobjects.add(10,10,300,200)
With mychart.seriescollection.newseries
  .XValues=range(cells(1,10), cells(5,10))
  .Values=range(cells(1,11), cells(5,11))
End with
```